# Ext.Ajax.defaultHeaders separator between headers

Tags: extjs, extjs3

In my project, I use :

```
Ext.Ajax.defaultHeaders = {
    'Content-type' : 'charset=iso-8859-1'
};
```

However, when I'm executing Ext.Ajax.Request to my server in some place of my project, in chrome developper tools, I'm seeing this, in the request header:

```
Content-type: 'charset=iso-8859-1, application/json'
```

The "," should be ";" to working.

Do you know why there is a "," instead of a ";" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should try

```
  Ext.Ajax.setDefaultHeaders({'Content-type': 'charset=iso-8859-1'});
```

instead of

```
  Ext.Ajax.defaultHeaders = {
      'Content-type' : 'charset=iso-8859-1'
  };
```